# JSONDecoder returning error when trying to parse nested JSON

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to parse a nested JSON for the last couple of days and I have no idea how to move forward.

At this point, I suspect that the trouble is a parameter received within the JSON named "data" which might cause a confusion between the param value in struct "VTResponse" and the data param that `URLSession.shared.dataTask` is getting.

Here's the code at this point:

```
import UIKit

struct VTResponse: Decodable {
    let data: [VT]
}

struct VT: Decodable {
    var id: String
}

let token = "<TOKEN>"
let XDOMAIN = "<XDOMAIN>"

guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.lalalla.com/subdomains") else {
            fatalError("Invalid URL")
}

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("x-apikey: \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(VTResponse.self, from: data)

if let result = result {
    result.data.forEach {
        print($0.id)
    }
            }
    else {
        print("Error")
    }
}.resume()
```

Assuming that I define a token and domain for the query, for example, lookup all of the **subdomains** of "giphy.com", the JSON response:

JSON Response - Pastebin

As you can see in the JSON response, the subdomains parameter ("id") is under a dictionary, under an array("data"). My guess is the code is trying to assign data to the variable:

```
guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
```

But this is just a guess. And even if so, how could I solve this?
Anyways, I'm getting the following output:

> Error

I'm trying to get the following output:

```
pingback.giphy.com
media3.giphy.com
api.giphy.com
developers.giphy.com
media.giphy.com
x-qa.giphy.com
media1.giphy.com
x.giphy.com
media4.giphy.com
media0.giphy.com
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any time you use `try?` instead of `do/try/catch`, you're throwing away the chance to print an actual error. I suggest you `print(error)` inside of the `catch`. Also, you can paste your JSON into https://app.quicktype.io and look at the models it generates for you

Comment: can you add: `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))`, just after
 `guard let data = data...`, and show us what it prints. Note, in my tests all works well, I get the expected output as you describe. I suspect you are receiving an error message from the server, maybe due to authorization. Try removing this `error == nil` from the guard.

Comment: You're right! I got an Authorization error. 
`Optional("{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"message\": \"X-Apikey header is missing\",\n        \"code\": \"AuthenticationRequiredError\"\n    }\n}")`
Yet, what's wrong? Why the API doesn't recognize the header I'm passing?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this api, but you could try using `"x-apikey \(token)"`, note no `:`. What does the docs say.

Comment: Nope that's not it, docs are referring to Python libraries mostly, furthermore, I couldn't find any resources about that API + Swift.

Comment: Have you tried: `request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-apikey")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using an `x-apikey` header for your token:

```
func fetchData(token: String, XDOMAIN: String, completion: @escaping (VTResponse) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/domains/\(XDOMAIN)/subdomains") else {
        fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-apikey") // <-- here
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { return } // todo return some error msg
        do {
            let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(VTResponse.self, from: data)
            return completion(results)
        } catch {
            print(error) // <-- here important
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And use it like this:

```
fetchData(token: "xxx", XDOMAIN: "www") { results in
    results.data.forEach {
        print("---> id: \($0.id)")
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: to get an array of `[String]`, that is, of `id`, use this function:

```
func ListFromSubDomains(token: String, XDOMAIN: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    fetchData(token: token, XDOMAIN: XDOMAIN) { results in
        completion(results.data.map{ $0.id })
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var IPList: [String] = []

ListFromSubDomains(token: "xxx", XDOMAIN: "www") { ids in
     IPList = ids
     print("---> ids: \(ids)")
}
```

Comment: And if I'd like to create an array from this function, how would I do that? I've tried the following:

```
func ListFromSubDomains (token: "xxx", XDOMAIN: "www") -> Array<String> {

    fetchData(token: "xxx", XDOMAIN: "www") { results in
        results.data.forEach {
            print("---> id: \($0.id)")
        }
}
```

Comment: updated my answer with more example code, to cater for your new question.

Comment: Yes, that one is very clear to me, but what I'm trying to achieve is the actual storing of this Array in a variable outside the function. For example, instead of `print("---> ids: \(ids)")` something like `let IPList = ids`

Comment: When you ask `... I'm trying to achieve is the actual storing of this Array in a variable outside the function.`
it means you really need to read  the Swift basics at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html. Updated my answer.